# Show favicons next to external links in BlogEngine.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, blogengine.net

I want show favicon for any external links in my post in BlogEngine.NET, So I use following code in my master page theme :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("a[href^='http']").each(function () {
            $(this).css({
                background: "url(http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=" + this.hostname +
                ") right center no-repeat",
                "padding-right": "20px"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But it shows favicons for all hyper links in page like page header and footer, navigation menu and etc.
I just want to show favicons in my post of blog not for entire page links.
I know that I must specify a css class name for above code, but I don't know how can do that.
All post in BlogEngine.NET are under a div tag with "***post***" css class name.

```
 <div id="ctl00_cphBody_PostList1_posts" class="posts">    
    <article id="post0" class="post">
           <h2 class="post-title">
        <div class="post-info Clear">
        <div class="post-body text">
        <p dir="rtl" style="text-align: right;">
            Some text...</p>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft1 </a> /* Favicon css does not effect here! */
              <span class="someclass1">
                 <p class="someclass2">
                    Some Text...
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft2 </a> /* Favicon css does not effect here! */
                 </p>
              </span>
        </div>
    </article>
```

How can I tell all links within the div with "***post***" css  class must shows favicon not all links in body page?
I use BlogEngine 2.9 .

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: How does your external links differs from internal?

Comment: All blog posts in BlogEngine.NET are under a div tag with "post" css class name. these are external links and they must have favicon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you could add something like this:

Here are 2 ways at jsfiddle: [Sample 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7LPF/1/) - [Sample 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7LPF/2/)

(I am not jQuery developer so it might have another/better syntax)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a[href^='http']").each(function () {

        // check if parent class name starts with post
        if (this.parentNode.className.substring(0, 4) == "post") {

            $(this).css({
                background: "url(http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=" + this.hostname +
                ") right center no-repeat",
                "padding-right": "20px"
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

If the parent is more far down the DOM, check the parents parent and so on.

```
        if (this.parentNode.parentNode.className.substring(0, 4) =....
```

If a class name is equal to "post"

```
        if (this.parentNode.className == "post") {
```

And you can combine it with one or more test

```
<div id="ctl00_cphBody_PostList1_posts" class="posts">
    <article id="post0" class="post">
        <h2 class="post-title">Title</h2>    
        <div class="post-info Clear">
            <div class="post-body text">
                <a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>
                <a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>


$("a[href^='http']").each(function () {

    if (this.parentNode.className.substring(0, 4).toLowerCase() == "post" &&
        this.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div" &&
        this.parentNode.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div" &&
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == "article"
       )
    {
        $(this).css({
            background: "url(http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=" + this.hostname + ") right center no-repeat", "padding-right": "20px"
        });
    }      
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I try your code but no favicon showing. (include external or internal links).  It seems that can't find "post" class name.

Comment: Post a part of the HTML please

Comment: Check my update ... it doesn't find it because the first parent wasn't the the one contain the "post" class, but any known class name can be used of the parent or you just check the parents parent, until you find the match

Comment: Updated again .. how to find class name that starts with "post", like "post0" or "post-body text" does

Comment: Unfortunately not working, following line encompass **post** class:<div id="ctl00_cphBody_PostList1_posts" class="posts"> (See my question again).

Comment: I updated my answer again .. showing how to check multiple attributes. To solve your issue is just a matter of finding the right values/attribute to check against, not the way to find it as I showed in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I try all suggested way, no one working for me. When I add an **if** condition all favicons remove from links (internal & external) and when remove the **if** all favicons shows.

Comment: I updated again .. as I said, no jQquery guy so I missed one thing, but now it work :) .. here is a test I did: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7LPF/

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work if hyper links located in another elements like another _div_ or _<P>_ tag with hierarchy and nested structure. Is there any way to create style for all elments in a special tag? for example all hyper links in a div with ***post*** class take favicons css? I want a top-down method like a tree search that search all post elements (include all it's childs and child childs and...) and find ***hyper links*** and set required favicons css for it!

Comment: This sample does work itself **down** through all **hyper links** and with the "if statements" you add the terms for when to add your css. Just add more test for the surroundings tags to narrow it down even more. If you check the last sample in my answer, you'll see how you can combine your terms in almost anyway you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, I did update my post too. If ***post*** div tag surrounds with multiple internal **div** or **<p>** tags, _parentNode_ returns <p> tag and not **"post-body text"** div tag so it does not take favicon required css class. I need a method that search for all links within the **"post-body text"** div as all nested tags for _hyperlinks_ and set favicon css for it. (In the updated question Microsoft link does not take favicon css!)

Comment: Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7LPF/1/) .. your links has either 2 or 4 parents so you check 2 and 4 levels up

Comment: Here is another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7LPF/2/) that grab div's with the class "post-body text"

Comment: OK, I got it. I must check for **parenNode** while I reach the **<div class="post-body text">** . Thanks again dude.